# Name of jar that contains com.tbf.xml.XmlParser

Tags: jar

I could not find the jar contains com.tbf.xml.XmlParser.

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: where is this class referenced? do you have it as an import or some tutorial?

Comment: nothing has been used. it is used to parse xml. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was inside breeze packages. Referred from auto generated classes.

Thanks